# Allow users to upload images with captions

Tags: php, mysql, html, image, upload

I need to allow users to upload images to my website. Currently, they can do that but it doesn't allow them to add a caption for the image they are uploading. I understand I will need  database. Could someone show me how to allow users to upload an image with a title? More details the better! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: As you know, you have to allow add title with image and save data. Its better and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to upload image by **$_FILE[]**,
then you will get array of it which contains attributes :

**$file ['name'], $file ['type'], $file ['size']** etc. 
If uploded file is "test.gif", you will get

$file['name']="test"..
If you want to change it with user defined caption then

just take $_POST['image_caption'] from form and append it

like:

**$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["member_photo"]["name"]));
$image_name= $_POST['image_caption'].".".$extension;**

Comment: But then there might be a name conflict. If two users upload image.jpg then the file system will have a problem. I want to be able to change the file names anyways. For example, image.jpg will be renamed to something random like asdf_223.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the related comment in a database with the image_id as the primary key, when you upload the image. That way, retrieving the image can retrieve the title, tags, comments, etc.

Comment: My question is how do I achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do this with PHP, you can start here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
That's fairly technical, but it's worth being aware of the information and there are a few examples.
Then just search Google for the many tutorials out there about uploading files.

Comment: I know how to allow users to upload files. I need to allow them to add titles and save that title to a database. Then I need the title of that image to be displayed with that image later on.